# Can't access element in the same view using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view, multiple-views

so in general I want to build a single page application with AngularJS and I want my page to have different content for public and registered users, thus I put my navbar, content and footer part into different views. The structure looks like this:

- index.html
- script.js
- navbar.html
- content.html
- footer.html
- uirouter.html

Here is the code for **uirouter.html**

```
<div ng-include="home.navbar"></div>
<div ng-include="home.content"></div>
<div ng-include="home.footer"></div>
```

And here is the code for **script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'RouteCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'uirouter.html'
  });
});

myApp.controller('RouteCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.home = {
    "navbar": "navbar.html"
    "content": "content.html",
    "footer": "footer.html"
  } 
});
```

And put the ng-app, ng-controller, and ng-view here in **index.html**

```
...
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="RouteCtrl" id="home" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-offset="100">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
...
```

All the views are loaded nicely but the problem is when I click the links on the navbar, such as "Features" and "Pricing" which should refer to each elements on the view, it doesn't work. Here how the **navbar.html** is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a> </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So the "Features" and "Pricing" should refer to these elements in **content.html**

```
...
<div id="containerfeatures" class="container"> 
  <div class="row mainFeatures" id="features">
...
<div class="row PageHead" id="pricing">
...
```

The page is being redirected instead of referring the elements, here is the url

```
http://localhost/app/#/pricing
```

which think it should be referred to this..

```
http://localhost/app/#pricing
```

I'm still new to AngularJS so I'm still wandering through my way here and there. This is the tutorial that I follow in doing this : [Use Multiple ng-view Single Page](http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/use-multiple-ng-view-single-page)

Would anyone please help pointing out my mistakes or what I should do to make them work? Any help would really be appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Or maybe there are other ways I could do to show multiple views? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added a /home and /features etc routes in the route provider in the config. Also href should be as shown by @charlietfl

Comment: thank you for the answer! it finally works by adding the route and the hashPrefix :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `/` to the `href`'s.

```
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
```

Or if you set hashPrefix (using `$locationProvider`) to `!` for SEO it would be

```
<a href="#!/home">Home</a>
```

Angular treats a `$location` path as looking like `'/pathpart1/pathpart2'`

Comment: Thank you, but adding both `/` and `!` to the `href`'s still doesn't work. It keeps redirecting to the same url.. so since the first path shown is the hashPrefix, would that mean the root is `/#` or how?

Comment: you have to declare the hashPrefix within `$locationProvider` (see docs) before you can use it in the html or url. That's why I gave you both scenarios. For root would use `#/`

Comment: thank you! finally managed it to work by adding the # and set it in the script!